# Validating multiple check boxes in PHP. Must check at least one but not more than three checkboxes

Tags: php, arrays, validation, checkbox

I am using PHP to create a voting system and I have a form that I am inserting into MySQL database.  I am going to use JavaScript to ensure that the user selects at least one candidate but not more than three, but I want to validate on the server side as well.  Here is the web form for the page:

```
<form method="post" action="post.php">
<input type="checkbox" name="vote[FR01]" value="ON"> Freshman Candidate 1 <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="vote[FR02]" value="ON"> Freshman Candidate 2 <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="vote[FR03]" value="ON"> Freshman Candidate 3 <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="vote[FR04]" value="ON"> Freshman Candidate 4 <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="vote[FR05]" value="ON"> Freshman Candidate 5 <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="vote[FR06]" value="ON"> Freshman Candidate 6 <br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

I know I will need to use a for loop however, could anyone explain how I could use those array key indexes which are the column names in the database?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $checkedCandidates = 0;
    $values = $_POST['vote'];
    $checkedCandidates = count($values);

    if ($checkedCandidates < 1) {
        echo 'You need to check at least one candidate.';
    } elseif ($checkedCandidates >= 4) {
        echo 'You can only check up to three candidates.';
    } else {
        echo 'Checked candidates: ' . var_dump($values);
    }
}
```

[image: Preview]

Comment: Why not `$values = $_POST['vote']; $checkedCandidates = count($values);`? I see no need for a loop here.

Comment: Thanks, never thought of that. Now looks more clean. Edited :)

Comment: No problem, what did you use to make the .gif BTW? If it's reasonably quick & easy, I'm very interested. As a Google Apps admin it's something I'd rather send to users with a 1 minute record then trying to write a foolproof description in 10 minutes with them still getting it wrong ;)

Comment: [LICEcap](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/). I made that gif in like 20 seconds and then just uploaded it here at Stackoverflow. Worked perfectly.

Comment: Ah, damn: _"(for Windows and now OSX)"_, that excludes me :(. Thanks anyway, I'll see if there's a comparable *nix package :)