# Having issue in my server side validation in checkbox?

Tags: php

Having issue in my server side validation in checkbox?Here I have listed three checkbox.it is mandatory user select any one checkbox.How to validate in server side using php.I have given mycode. I have written using OR condition.if all the checkbox is null.it shows error,I don't want this.my issue is user select any one in three checkbox.how to validate in server side?
 **My Form:**

```
 <form name="vk" action="" method="post"/>
    <?php
    if($error!='') 
    {
    ?>
    <div style="color:#FF0000;"><?php echo $error;?></div>
    <?php 
    }
    ?>
    </td>
    </tr>
    Name:<input type="name" name="username" value=""/><br/><br/>
    password:<input type="password" name="password" value=""/><br/><br/>
    Please select subject<input type="checkbox" name="allsubject" id="all" value="allsubject">All Subject
    <input type="checkbox" name="science"  value="science">Science
    <input type="checkbox" name="maths"  value="maths">Maths
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
 </form>
```

**My php code:**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    $name=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    $allsubject=$_POST['allsubject'];
    $science=$_POST['science'];
    $maths=$_POST['maths'];
    $error='';
    if($name=='')
    {
    $error.='name Id required.<br/>';
    }
    if($password=='')
    {
    $error.='Password required.<br/>'; 
    }
        if(empty($allsubject) || empty($science)  || empty($maths))
  {
     $error.="You didn't select any subject.";
  }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: check this if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21467253/validating-multiple-check-boxes-in-php-must-check-at-least-one-but-not-more-tha

Answer (score 1):

The checkbox only used type Boolean values, means that only work using "true or false.

```
if($allsubject == true || $science == true || $maths == true)
{
$error.='subject required.<br/>';
```

}

Comment: Thanks  I have given like this f($allsubject == false || $science == false || $maths == false)
{
$error.='subject required.<br/>'; 
} can you make it little proper because user select any one checkbox. we have done with all field==false.this is not correct .I thing can you give any solution

Comment: Here the form is not array I am using the checkbox individual name to get the values.again I am asking user picks any  subject.but it should not be null .user picks among three any one.

Comment: Well I understand what your trying to do in this case your code should be like this.

elseif($allsubject == true){
 $science = true;  $maths = true;
Echo "All subjects have been selected";
} 

elseif($maths == true){ Echo "The subjects Maths have been selected"; } 

elseif($science == true){ Echo "The subjects science have been selected";}

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, name of checkboxes should same and their values differs:

Please select subject

```
<input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" id="all" value="all">All Subject
<input type="checkbox" name="subject[]"  value="science">Science
<input type="checkbox" name="subject[]"  value="maths">Maths
```

The corresponding php code would be

```
$subjectSelected = $_POST['subject'];
if(empty($subjectSelected) || (count($subjectSelected) < 1)) {
    $error.='subject required.<br/>'; 
}
```

though second OR is not required in if condition, it would be good if you put it.

Comment: Thanks lot .thanks for guiding me,if i echo the $subjectSelected variable only the last value is coming.for ex if am selected science,maths, only maths is displaying. science is not coming what is the issue here?

Comment: I am getting only last value what is the issue here $_POST['subject'] gives only one value shall I want to make the name=subject to name=subject[]

Comment: sorry, i missed that. html name should be subject[].